# Copy a data range and then insert blank rows every after a certain value

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm copying a range of data (one column only) using **QUERY()**, however, I am trying to find a way to insert blank rows whenever a certain value is shown.

[image: screenshot from sample sheet]

here, I'm trying to insert 2 blank rows whenever the value **b1** shows. I've been trying to accomplish this with some query() and arrayformula() formula but I'm not getting close. **We're trying to complete this using formula only (no scripts)**

Here's the sample [sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QG5sNx_C3dKOvAxvcV7T4pJxiWBhoSHHxRsIE3l9Y8M/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

My solution is:

```
=query(flatten(ArrayFormula(split(transpose("b1 & & "&split(ArrayFormula(textjoin("&",1,A5:A)),"b1",0,1)),"&",1,0))),"select Col1 where Col1 is not null offset 2")
```

This is not perfect as there are spaces instead of blank rows. But I hope it might help you.

[image]